# Divide-by-zero encountered: rhok assumed large error using scipy.optimizor

Tags: scipy, divide-by-zero

I used `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs` to minimize the hinge loss (SVM). However, there are errors :

> Divide-by-zero encountered: rhok assumed large.

Somebody said that “It had to do with the training data set”， anybody knows how to deal with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L891) of scipy, rhok is,

```
rhok = 1.0 / (numpy.dot(yk, sk))
```

where both `yk` and `sk` depend on intput array `x0`.

A possible causes of this error may be a bad choice of initial condition `x0` which tends to singularities in your function `f`. I would suggest plotting your function and maybe ensuring initial conditions are always away from possible divergent values. If this is part of a larger training routine, you could possibly use `try` and on catching an `ZeroDivisionError` try shifting the initial condition shifted by some amount. You may also find a different minimisation method is more robust from scipy [minimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize).

If you add the `full_output` option to `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs` it should give you more information about you particular case.